# Android-L ActionBar ProgressBar not showing up

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to utilize the ProgressBar thats included in the ActionBar by calling it this way in my Activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle aSavedState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.PROGRESS_START);

    setProgress(10);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);

    super.onCreate(aSavedState);
```

You'd think that will all those feature requests, one would make it show up.

How do you do this?

Comment: if it is support library - supportRequestWindowFeature

Comment: im only compiling 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1', not v7 or v13, i wonder if i need those

Comment: Known issue, see https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=891